# VS 2013 Azure Publish hangs with last Pubxml file

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-sdk-.net, pubxml

If I publish to Azure Cloud Service using the Cloud Project and follow the publish wizard from it works fine but **only** if I delete the last Pubxml file (stored in the profile folder) first.

If I try and publish when a Pubxml file already exists it will hang trying to navigate between wizard steps.

Using SDK V2.9.6, although had the same issue on previous versions.

I have multiple subscriptions, and the issue seems to be whilst the Pubxml does store the subscription, it is ignored and the default (first one in the list alphabetically) is used instead.

So if I run a publish where there was a previous Pubxml, it jumps to the Diagnostics page. I click next for the summary and the issue areas are highlighted with a red error indicator (it has the wrong subscription selected by default, and hence it cannot find the correct cloud service). However I cannot click back as it just hangs.

Comment: As a workaround, I have edited my Subscription name so the main one I want to use is first in the list alphabetically. This works so I do not need to delete the Pubxml file, but only for this project and subscription so clearly not a solution.

Comment: What's the reason you're not using VS'2015? It is backwards compatible with 2013 projects.

Comment: Surely this is not the reason?

Comment: Have updated inline with @jina feedback as Subscription ID is included in the Pubxml, however it seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using SDK V2.9.6, and didn't see this problem. Actually, my pubxml files have subscription information included.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <AzureCredentials>{"ServiceManagementEndpoint":"https:\/\/management.core.windows.net\/","ResourceManagementEndpoint":"https:\/\/management.azure.com\/","SubscriptionId":"my-subscription-id"}</AzureCredentials>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Which version of Azure SDK is your pubxml files generated from?

Comment: This should have been a comment, not an answer (code not included). With a bit more reputation, 
[you will be able to post comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Same version as you, V2.9.6, and yes you are correct, my mistake, the sub id is included, however it must be being ignored. I will update the question.

Comment: Is the subscription Id in pubXml the one you want? @Jezbers

Comment: @Jezbers, could you open your ccproj in a editor, and check the ProductVersion?

Comment: @jina <ProductVersion>2.9</ProductVersion>